# My Node Red dashboard disappeared, my app says "not running" but won't restart

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I am starting from the position of *near* absolute ignorance here.

I successfully set up a Bluemix account, added devices, got API keys, connected my Raspberry Pi running Node Red and a temperature sensor to Node Red on Bluemix, created a dashboard and was able to get data back and forth between Watson/Bluemix and my Pi.  Cool.  Unfortunately, I got all that way without ever really understanding the navigation of Watson/Bluemix nor all the terminology.  I made NR work both ways and was happy.
Then one day last week, the route to my Bluemix Node Red application stopped being accessible:

> 404 Not Found: Requested route ('misterpi-01.mybluemix.net') does not exist.

[image: Cloud Foundry App not running]

I can browse my devices and see that they are sending data every few minutes, so clearly the connection is there.  When I click on IBM Cloud Apps, I am told

> There are no IBM Cloud applications bound to your organization

When I am on my IBM Cloud Dashboard and I click on Connections I see I have a connected application that is "Not Running" with a red dot.  I can click Stop and the status goes to Stopped.  When I click Start, after a short while,

[image: the status returns to Not Running]

I cannot add an another app because I can only have one.

Where did my NR app go and can I get it back (preferred) and if not, delete it?

At the suggestion of @hardillb I went looking for logs.  I found them and it looks like the app is continuously started and crashing.  I can't copy the text from the error logs but here is a screenshot.

[image: error log entries from my not running app]

Comment: The dashboard will have a link to the logs for the app, That should contain information about why the app crashed and why it fails to restart

Comment: After some poking around, I found the logs.  Interpreting them is a completely different story. It looks like the app is continuously started and crashing.  I see npm errors and other interesting things but I cannot copy the text from the errors to paste here.

Comment: Do not post pictures of log output, paste the text so it's searchable

Comment: I'd love to, but either I could not (select/copy text from web page) or I was unable to because I don't know how.  I received an email on the 12th saying "Because you haven't been actively developing, your apps will sleep in 2 day(s). This means your apps will stop running and won't be accessible to visitors."  Now the page where I got the log snapshot above shows no log data.  I assume this is because everything has been put to sleep and I am done. At this point I begin to conclude that this is not for the beginner. But thanks for trying to lead me to help myself.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is get a copy of your flow source for backup. Go into the IBM Cloud Dashboard and click on `Cloudant-ll` (the suffix may be different?) and then `Launch Cloudant Dashboard` (alternatively, click on `...-cloudantNoSQLDB` and then `alias of Cloudant-ll`). From there click on `NodeRed` and then select the id that ends with "/flow". Then you can extract everything inside `"flow": []`.

I would recommend emptying it out so you have no flows to ensure that Bluemix can start 'empty'. If you do this you will end up with something similar to mine below (don't change `_rev`).

```
{
  "_id": "Home Assistant/flow",
  "_rev": "102-2b38e1756eeb26def19b20858bc50a40",
  "flow": []
}
```

Later you can paste the extracted code back into Node Red using `Import > Clipboard`.

You may also want to edit the ".../settings" document to remove any extra node types you installed.

Caveat - I had the same problems with Bluemix and eventually gave up - crashing at least weekly running out of memory and difficulty restarting. I suspect it can't reliably run with 256MB.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Just to make sure we are on the same page:  Is the `IBM Cloud Dashboard` what I find at `https://console.bluemix.net/dashboard/apps`?  If so, I don't see a `Cloudant-ll` but rather a `Cloudant-zk` and when I click on that, I get `{"message":"InternalServiceError"}`.  If I'm looking at the wrong dashboard, can you give me a hint where to find it?  I absolutely cannot parse the navigation of this service.

Comment: It's probably the same thing - ll or zk are maybe a random suffix. The error doesn't look promising. You can get there a different way - I have updated the answer to include that as well. You may have to go that way to start the database service if it has gone into deep sleep.

Comment: Progress.
The path through `cloudantNoSQLDB` is a blank page, path through `Cloudant-zk` leads to `node-red`, w/ 4 "docs". NR leads to my flow etc. Backed up and cleared the flow for an "empty" start per suggestion. Stopped/Started app. App runs briefly then stops.  Logs have entries again, lots of `npm ERR!` entries and `/home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log`. Also `npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:` and `npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the iot-bluemix package`.
Pi sending data, can see in Bluemix. NR is broken. Delete and re-create?

Comment: Now that you've got a backup of your flows, there's no harm in doing so. However, without knowing how it got like that, there's no reason it won't happen again. When I had significant problems I abandoned that IBM Id and set up a new one from scratch with another of my email addresses.

Comment: On 12/16 I created a support case but haven't heard back yet.  As you so correctly point out, not knowing why it happened prevents me from making corrections to prevent it from happening again. I have a couple of contacts that I may call on to see if I can get an answer.  I'll leave this open until they respond or I get tired of waiting.  @Michael thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with log/errors and endpoint 404:
I followed Michaels advice to backup (nodered:flows and settings) in cloudant.

```
1. However what works(for now) was cleaning part of the nodered /settings.
2. Basically I removed the nodes part from the Json up until almost the end, leave _credentialSecret part at the end.
3. restart and go to your url, you will see your flows
4. if your flows use some nodes that produce warnings, it might be necessary to remove them to avoid future problems.
```

UPDATE 2: I saved every flow separately, and then deleted them all from the nodered flows. Then restarted, and have been importing one by one, and it is working.