# Node-red in IBM Bluemix crashes while starting after sleeping (lite account)

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

After sleeping (in lite account type) node-red, created by node-red starter kit, crashes while starting. It is possible to login in editor for a few seconds and then it crashes with error code "an instance of the app crashed: APP/PROC/WEB: Exite with status 1 (out of memory)". Dashboard (node-red-dashboard) was installed before sleeping and worked correctly.

I tried to restart Node-RED, Stop and Start.

Comment: I had the same problem and gave up. See my answer to the same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756668/my-node-red-dashboard-disappeared-my-app-says-not-running-but-wont-restart/53807441#53807441. You could try upgrading to pay-as-you-go (which is still free unless you use paid services), because that gives you an extra 256MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. The problem may be due to the memory overflow in the container Garden. Taking into account that the content is stored in the cache, the application cannot start after the restart process, it issues an Exit status 1 (out of memory) error.
The cache is updated only by pushing the application into the cloud.
An option that was checked for application recovery:

1. View the name of the database for NodeRED (which stores all information about the Node-RED) in Cloudant, for example, "nodered."
2. Install to PC Cloud Foundry Command Line Interface - CLI https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/install-go-cli.html
3. Download from github and unarchive the application's code  bluemix-starter  https://github.com/knolleary/node-red-bluemix-starter (clone or download -> download zip)
4. In the downloaded folder add a record to a manifest file (manifest.yml) in the env section, in which set the database name (for example, nodered) in Cloudant to environment variable NODE_RED_STORAGE_DB_NAME. Four spaces must be made before NODE_RED_STORAGE_DB_NAME. It is better to make changes using the Notepad ++ editor.

---

```
---
applications:
- memory: 256M
  env:
    OPTIMIZE_MEMORY: true
    NODE_RED_STORAGE_DB_NAME: nodered 
  command: node index.js --settings ./bluemix-settings.js –v
```

Save the file after changing.

5. Run the command line (cmd) and then:

a.  go to a folder with a downloaded project, such as Windows

```
cd c:/node-red-bluemix-starter
```

b.  specify the api endpoint where the application is located, in our case:

```
cf api https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
```

c.  send a registration command in the cloud

```
cf login
```

d.  specify the mail and password (password is entered without explicit character display)

e.  pushing the project by specifying the name of your instance Node-RED, for example NameApp

```
cf push NameApp
```